# Google Chrome Rendering

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, rendering

My Google Chrome (version 40.0.2214.93 m) can't render some fonts. Icon packages such as font-awesome are shows as a blank square, and monospaced fonts such as courier-new are shown as Arial.

This is how Font-Awesome's website appears to me: http://goo.gl/jPC5Qm

**UPDATE:**

This is a new behavior in Chrome, but in Mozilla Firefox the rendering works perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?  Chrome recently changed how font is displayed have you tried switching back to the old behavior?  Can you tell us if this is a new problem or an old problem?  it would be helpful if you updated the question with this information.

Comment: Works fine here with 40.0.2214.93 m. Have you tried with a clean profile/disabling extensions ... ?